# Could NOT find Qt5WebKitWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, owncloud, nextcloud

I am trying to build nextcloud open source project. I am using built tools Qt 5.6 version. following errors has occurred-

> -- Could NOT find Qt5WebKitWidgets (missing: Qt5WebKitWidgets_DIR)

CMake Warning at src/gui/CMakeLists.txt:313 (find_package):

> Found package configuration file:
>
> C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake

but it sets Qt5_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt5" is considered to be NOT
FOUND.  Reason given by package:

> Failed to find Qt5 component "WebKitWidgets" config file at
>   C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/cmake/Qt5WebKitWidgets/
>   Qt5WebKitWidgetsConfig.cmake

Comment: In Windows, you need Visual Studio tools to work with QWebEngine, not mingw.

Comment: As of Qt 5.6 QtWebKitWidgets is not available by default, it was replaced by Qt WebEngine, but unfortunately it is not available for MinGW. QtWebkit and QtWebKitWidgets are no longer developed by Qt, but it still exists, it has independent developers, so you can download and compile it manually, although I do not know how to do it with the tool you use.

Comment: Is QtWebkit and QtWebKitWidgets  available for lower version of Qt?? @Bobur

Comment: user2893186 I don't really know. As @eyllanesc points out, it is available for <5.6 versions of Qt.

Comment: @user2893186 It is not officially available by Qt, but you can compile for later versions: https://github.com/qt/qtwebkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.finally I have got solution.I have just used Qt 5.5 version which solves my problem.